# Child work types inheriting field values from parent item

Tags: azure-devops

I am working through creating a custom process in Azure DevOps and was curious if field values from parent can be shared with child items.

Here is an example:

1. Create field 'Custom Field 9' on Epic work type
2. Create the same field 'Custom Field 9' on Product Backlog Item work type
3. Create an epic and fill in the value of 'Custom Field 9'
4. Create a child Product Backlog Item, 'Custom Field 9' is then inherited to the backlog items field.

What I've tried so far is to use a rule on either Epic or Product Backlog Item, however, I do not believe the rules can apply to creation of children processes.

One other option I'm going to try later today is a Flow that detects when a child work item is created and perform it automatically. I'd like to try to keep this contained to Azure DevOps if possible.

Edit: Thought it helpful to mention that we are using the hosted solution of DevOps and nothing on premise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to say that as default, there does not such a work item features with "out of the box". But you can use another tool to achieve this.

Like you said, Microsoft Flow, there does not such feature supported while connect with Azure Devops.

But, in addiiton, I think you can do this with writing some custom scripts. And then configure [Web hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) to trigger this custom events.

Also, here has another tool named [TFS Aggregator (Web Service)](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/) to achieve what you want. You can set and configure apply certain rules (such as copying fields from a parent item to a child item). And it will trigger after a work item is created or saved.

I know this is very inconvenient, here has an [same feature suggest](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/385158/copying-field-values-from-parent-work-item-by-crea.html) which raised by others. They has the same demand with you. You can vote and comment for this suggestion. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

[image]

Comment: The web hook link is promising. I am able to create the trigger in the area path and against a product backlog item. I've yet to create custom scripts for DevOps, is this something I can do if we are using the hosted platform?

Comment: Soory about late response. Yes, of course you can. As you can see in this [Web Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops), it showed the way which can be used to the org hosted on VSTS.

Comment: Hi @DouglasKorinke I'm trying to find a solution similar to what you wanted to do. Can you share how you used Web Hooks for this task? Sorry as I have basically no experience with it. Thanks

Comment: You can do this with Power Apps Flows, it has a standard connector to Azure DevOps, but you can also do it manually using a HTTP request trigger and configuring DevOps web hooks to send to the connector url

Answer (score 4):

I needed this feature as well, but in it's absence I have got it to work (relatively easily) with an Azure Logic App (for anyone also using Azure)

​Trigger

When a work item is created

Then

​Get work item details using "Parent" as the work item ID to search for

​Finally

​Update the new work item with any field from the parent you require

[image]
​
​